# Where is the "airshipconfig.properties"?

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I've been following the tutorial for implementing Urban Airship functionality, but I'm stuck at this step:

```
4. Open your airshipconfig.properties file and add the following line...
```

I don't know where to find this file. It is definitely not inside my Android project.

The next instruction is also confusing, because I have no idea what an "app secret" is:

```
5. Make sure you set developmentAppKey, developmentAppSecret, 
   productionAppKey, and productionAppSecret...
```

Can someone please clarify these for me? Thanks

Comment: I think you should create your own 'airshipconfig.properties' file inside of your Android project structure

Comment: Thanks @art-divin, but it explicitly states to **open** it, so maybe I'm not getting something

Comment: I believe you just create the file and put it in your assets folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it is not necessary to have `airshipconfig.properties` at all. All the properties from that file can be set programmatically. This is what worked for me, in `onCreate` of my `Application` file:

```
AirshipConfigOptions options = 
        AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this.getApplicationContext());

if (!options.isValid()) {
    options.gcmSender = "932487653294";
    options.transport = "gcm";
    options.developmentAppKey = "41fdslhbc827dgc2cdj";
    options.developmentAppSecret = "svigivyeubwohubvsdv";
    options.productionAppKey = "41fdslhbc827dgc2cdj";
    options.productionAppSecret = "svigivyeubwohubvsdv";
    options.inProduction = true;
    options.richPushEnabled = true;
}

UAirship.takeOff(this, options);

PushManager.enablePush();

String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
Log.i("my_tag", "My Application onCreate - App APID: " + apid);

PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
```

Comment: setting programmatically is preferable for us too. +1

Comment: But what is supposed to be the "developmentAppSecret" ??

Comment: @shailesh if you go to urbanairship website and visit your application under settings if you see Api Keys you should be able to see App Key, App Secret and App Master Secret

Answer (score 1):

If you did want to have the properties, it's meant to go in your `src/main/assets` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create the application in your Urban Airship account, you will get Appkey and AppSecret.

The credentials have to be integrated in the application.

It can be done in two ways

1) in the assets folder(in airshipconfig.properties file).
2) in the application class.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you can find your airshipconfig.properties file, assuming you are using Android Studio to compile your project:

```
app\src\main\assets\airshipconfig.properties
```

You can find the corresponding developmentAppKey, developmentAppSecret, productionAppKey, and productionAppSecret at urbanairship.com from your account.